# Code behind Content editor button for Experience editor button

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore8

Is it possible to use a code behind of a command used for ribbon button in content editor as a request for experience editor button? We want to stick to SPEAK and not make any changes to `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config`.

After creating new button in Experience editor, telling .js to call `NewCommand` request by

```
Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("ExperienceEditor.NewCommand");
```

that was referenced in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Requests.config` as

```
<request name="ExperienceEditor.NewCommand" type="Sitecore.Starterkit.customcode.MyCommand,MyProject"/>
```

nothing happens and logs say

```
ERROR Could not instantiate speak request object, 
name:ExperienceEditor.NewCommand, 
type:Sitecore.Starterkit.customcode.MyCommand,MyProject`
```

Do we have to import `PipelineProcessorRequest` as suggested by some tutorials or is there a way to use our existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use my existing control using guidelines from:

http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-ribbon-button-transfiguration/

Relevant pieces of the old command:

```
if (args.IsPostBack)
{
    // act upon the dialog completion
    if (args.Result == "yes")
    {
        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, "item:load(...)");
    }
}
else
{
    // trigger the dialog
    UrlString url = new UrlString(UIUtil.GetUri("control:CopyLanguage"));
    url.Add("id", item.ID.ToString());
    url.Add("lang", item.Language.ToString());
    url.Add("ver", item.Version.ToString());
    SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(url.ToString(), true);
    args.WaitForPostBack();
}
```

The redressed command:

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
    Sitecore.Commands.ScoreLanguageTools = {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            return true; // we will get back to this one
        },
        execute: function (context) {
            var id = context.currentContext.itemId;
            var lang = context.currentContext.language;
            var ver = context.currentContext.version;

            var path = "/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=CopyLanguage" +
                       "&id=" + id + "&lang=" + lang + "&ver=" + ver;

            var features = "dialogHeight: 600px;dialogWidth: 500px;";

            Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(
                path, '', features, null, 
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        window.top.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this blog post on adding custom SPEAK command buttons to Sitecore 8 Experience Editor?

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/the%20editing%20tools/customize%20the%20experience%20editor%20ribbon

Otherwise if that doesn't achieve what your looking for, it might be worth trying to standard SPEAK application way of triggering a button, In a SPEAK application you can call a JavaScript function from a button click using this code.

```
javascript:app.FunctionName();
```

In the core DB update the click field on your button to call JavaScript with the javascript: prefix. Does this allow you to trigger your JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, Sobek. I have already seen the link you provided, but it was not helpful. Calling javascript function from a button click as you described doesn't do anything either. Perhaps there is something wrong with my .js call to `NewCommand` request?